# Having trouble in removing extra or special chars from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string, eval

I have a function for removing extra or special chars:

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
return unsafe
     .replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "")
     .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ")
     .replace(/\s+/g," ")
     .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
     .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
     .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
     .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
     .replace(/'/g, "&#039;")
     .replace(/!/g, "");
   }
```

While I am calling it and this part of my code looks like:

```
$(".product_json", data).each(function(){
    var thisH = $(this).html();
    var myNewString = eval( '('+ thisH +')');
    var toBeEscaped = myNewString.item_description;
    var escapedString = escapeHtml(toBeEscaped);
    myNewString.item_description = escapedString;
    myNewString = JSON.stringify(myNewString);
        console.log(myNewString);
//product_json.push( jQuery.parseJSON( myNewString ) );
});
```

But some how it says in console: `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`

Data in this field looks like

```
VINOVO - Lotti TERRENO Hobbystico - Campestre!!! <br />
```

Comment: The code is fine so it's the data that's causing the issue.  Can you supply example data that causes the error, or even better a jsfiddle that shows it?

Comment: Which line is generating that error?

Comment: @Trott this one: var myNewString = eval( '('+ thisH +')');

Comment: And what is the value of `thisH` at that point?

Comment: @user1433900: That means the "JSON" isn't valid.

Comment: @Trott Please see this screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/EWg267OJ3

Comment: @Rocket Yes I know that but I am trying to make it valid as I do not have full control over JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign a value to `thisH` in this line:

```
var thisH = $(this).html();
```

And then running it through `eval()` (surrounded by parentheses) in this line:

```
var myNewString = eval( '('+ thisH +')');
```

Use a debugger to check the value of `thisH` when the SyntaxError is triggered. Is it valid JavaScript when surrounded by parentheses? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: this is the url: http://diventarepartner.unicaimmobili.com/proposte-immobiliari/risultato-ricerca-immobili

Comment: I have console.log(thisH) before eval and problemetic data looks like this:{"item_id": "4271054","foto_principale":"{tag_foto principale_value}", "item_localita":"", "item_provincia":"TO", "item_tipologia":"Altro", "item_mq":"400", "item_contratto":"vendita", "item_prezzo":"30000", "item_locali":"1", "item_zona":"mt 500 dal centro" , "item_strada":"via", "item_indirizzo":"" , "item_civico":"", "item_logoagenzia":"/resource/loghi/medium/102.gif", "item_description":"VINOVO - Lotti TERRENO Hobbystico - Campestre!!! 
 A mt. 500 dal centro paese, adiacente a zona res.."}

Comment: Please look at  Campestre!!! 
it has some kind of line break